# I need to compare the responses of one group of participants to two different tests.

Tags: r

I need to compare the responses of one group of participants to two different tests. The answers that the participants had to provide on those tests were 1 CORRECT and 2 INCORRECT. For example, I have 65 participants who provided CORRECT answers and 35 INCORRECT answers on test 1. On the other hand, I have 45 participants who provided CORRECT answers and 55 INCORRECT answers on test 2. I need to determine whether there is any significant difference in their responses to test 1 and test 2. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case for McNemar's test.  But you need to set up the data so that you have a count for those who provided a correct answer on 1 and correct answer on 2; Correct answer on 1 and incorrect answer on 2; and so on.

This requires that you can pair the answer on Test 2 with the same person on Test 1.

Let's say you have data such as:

```
            Test2
Test1       Correct   Incorrect
Correct      30        35          = 65
Incorrect    15        20          = 35
            -----     -----
             45        55
```

These match the data in your example, and you can see that the total participants are 100.

```
Input =("
Test1       Correct   Incorrect
Correct      30        35
Incorrect    15        20
")

Matrix = as.matrix(read.table(textConnection(Input),
                   header=TRUE,
                   row.names=1))

mcnemar.test(Matrix)

   ### McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction
   ###
   ### McNemar's chi-squared = 7.22, df = 1, p-value = 0.00721
```

Essentially this is a test of symmetry.  Ignoring the Correct/Correct and Incorrect/Incorrect cells, this test asks, is the 35 value sufficiently larger than the 15 value?  If so, we might conclude that Test 2 was more difficult, or at least that students did worse on Test 2 when compared to Test 1, considering that the same students took both tests.

An effect size statistic gives us a measure of how large this difference is.  Here, we'll use odds ratio.

```
OR = 35 / 15
OR

   ### 2.33
```

An odds ratio of 2.33 [might be considered a medium effect size](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_05.html).